# How to add Manifest permissions to Android with no manifest?

Tags: android, android-manifest

From What I've seen on other guides, you add a line of XML code between manifest brackets but I don't have any manifest brackets to begin with.

So everyone says put permission between manifest like so:

```
<manifest xlmns:android...>
 ...
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
</manifest>
```

But I don't have any  period, this is my main_activity.XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >



    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/group"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/add"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Add New" 
            android:onClick="onClick"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/delete"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Delete First" 
            android:onClick="onClick"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="114dp" >

    </ListView>

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

How could I grant permission to use internet?

Answer (score 1):

You have to add this into your AndroidManifest.xml file, not into a layout/*.xml
Normally, you can find it in your project root.

Answer (score 0):

`AndroidManifest.xml` file will always be in android project. Check properly.

Answer (score 0):

Manifest is not inside any folders specifically. It's only inside your App's root folder. See:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> This (main_activity.XML) is your layout XML not the
>   AndroidManifest.xml Find your AndroidManifest.xml in root folder.